# Delete Duplicate ROWS and add keep 1 Rows in a .CSV File

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Looking for your expert view/suggestion for a VBA script for a .CSV File which can do below steps. I have tried macros but it's not working as exopected.

.CSV Input File
[image: .CSV Input File]

1. DELETE all ROWS which contains "Product Category=HN"
2. If multiple ROWS for One Product No. then DELETE multiple repeative ROWS and keep only One Row of that Product No. and add Total Quantity in Qunatity Column for that Product. 
   e.g. For Product No. 107 we have total 3 Rows so we need to Delete other 2 Rows and Keep One Rows as it is and in Quantity Column = 3"
3. DELETE 1 Additional Column "Display Name" at the beginning.
4. ADD 3 EMPTY ROWS on TOP.
5. so the Final Output should be like as mentioned below.

.CSV Output File
[image: .CSV Output File]

```
Sub DeleteProductCategoryHN()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For X = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    For Y = 1 To lastrow    
        If Cells(X, 5).Value = "HN" Then
            Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
End Sub
_____________________________________________________
Sub DeleteMultipleRows()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For X = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    For Y = 1 To lastrow   
        If Cells(X, 2).Value = Cells(Y, 2).Value And X > Y Then
            Cells(Y, 3).Value = Cells(X, 3).Value + Cells(Y, 3).Value
            Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub DeleteFirstColumn()
        Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: To avoid collecting down-votes for appearing to solicit free code please post the code you have tried and point to the line or lines in it where you need help.

Comment: My "expert" suggestion would be to do some research on how to do that and start writing a code, because such a macro does not exist ready to use and it is very unlikely that anyone will write the code for you for free. • Once you have tried something and you have a question to your code you can come back and we can assist you to fix/improve it. But note that a list of requirements is not a question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I do have written codes and its working as well for Step 1 and 2. Also i am writing for others also. But i have written separate code for each step. Now my Query is can we write to accommodate all steps in a single code or not. Need your suggestion on this. Thanks.

Comment: Sub DeleteProductCategoryHN()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For X = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    For Y = 1 To lastrow    
        If Cells(X, 5).Value = "HN" Then
            Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
End Sub
_____________________________________________________

Comment: Sub DeleteMultipleRows()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For X = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    For Y = 1 To lastrow   
        If Cells(X, 2).Value = Cells(Y, 2).Value And X > Y Then
            Cells(Y, 3).Value = Cells(X, 3).Value + Cells(Y, 3).Value
            Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code there. We cannot understand too much from the comment...

Comment: Hello FaneDuru .. i have added my code. my code is working fine for all my requirements but i have separate code. What i need is to have one code who can perform all above 4 Steps. Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion please to club all requirement in a Single code. Thanks.